# VS code conditional breakpoint does not work (python, platformio)

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I tried to add conditional break point in `platformio (nrf51DK arduino)` where I had some problems. To check what is wrong I wrote a simple python script. I have installed python, `pylance`. My python version is `3.9.9`.

I wrote simple code:

```
a=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
a+=1
print(a)
```

[view from debbuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIsSO.png)

I tried to add many conditional break-point similarly to tutorial from web. To my script I add e.g. "a>9". I understand this like "when variable a will be greater than 9 program should stop". But nothing was happening.

I also tried to install vs code insiders and there was the same situation. And in platformio the same. Previously I used keil for nrf board where conditional break-point like that works for me.

Now I think that I missed sth but spend time to check without success. I put python easiest example to show what is the nature of problem and because I can't find simple example.

To be pricise. I need to specify condition for example some variable change, or be greater than sth and when it hapenned program sholud stop on line where it was made.
It is possible in VScode?

Answer (score 0):

You understand the use of the breakpoint incorrectly。
If the breakpoint condition is true, the program will be interrupted.
The value of a at the conditional breakpoint you added is 3. If a > 9 is not met, the execution will continue.
You can try to add a conditional breakpoint on the tenth line below. Then the program will break.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer.
This is my first question and I may not clearly describe situation. Maybe I'm correctly understand conditional breakpoint in VScode.
As you suggest add conditional breakpoint in line below and it works.
But I need to specify condition, for example change some value and when it chapend break program in line where it uccured.
It is possible?

Comment: @macieks95 it depends if the debugger used support this type of breakpoint, the debugger interface might support it but that does not mean the debugger does

Comment: Maybe you can take the negation of your original judgment condition to interrupt the program, ha ha

Comment: @rioV8 This is reason why I used python for that. I checked and python should be right for that

Comment: @张明杰 Nope, still nothing

Comment: @macieks95 I think I need more information, such as the operation process and breakpoint expression in your example. It's best to upload it in the form of video, so that I can better help you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we code like this:

```
def aaa():
    a = 0
    for i in range(50):
        a += 1
    print(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aaa()
```

Then add a condition breakpoint at the line of `a+=1`.

In the example you have provided, you can add the condition breakpoint at each line of `a+=1`. But usually, we will not meet too many lines which contain the same variable. If you meet, you just need to add some more condition breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture you have defined a [Function Breakpoint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_function-breakpoints) (triangle mark).

You will break on entering the function `a>5`, there is no such function and it is even an illegal function name.

You can add a `condition` and/or a `hitcount` to a Function breakpoint but that will not help you because it only gets evaluated at function entry.

The DAP supports [Data breakpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_data-breakpoints) but in my version of `vscode-python` I can't find any UI in the VARIABLES view that might create a Data breakpoint.